# Index a string in bash

Tags: bash, shell, string

How can I refer to a string by index in sh/bash? That is, basically splitting it.

I am trying to strip 5 characters of a file name. All names have the structure: name_nr_code. I am trying to remove the 5 alphanumeric code bit. `name_nr_` is always 10 characters.

Is there a thing like;

`for i in * ; do mv "$i" "$i"[:10] ; done`

Comment: Why the `bash` tag if you're asking for a `sh` solution?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Simple as this.

(bash)

```
for i in * ; do mv -- "$i" "${i:0:5}" ; done
```

Voila.

And an explanation from *[Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) ([Chapter 10. Manipulating Variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/manipulatingvars.html))*, (with extra **<kbd>NOTE</kbd>**s inline to highlight the errors in that manual):

> **Substring Extraction**
>
> ```
> ${string:position}
> ```
>
> Extracts substring from *`$string`* at *`$position`*.
>
> If the `$string` parameter is "*" or "@", then this extracts the positional parameters, starting at `$position`.
>
> ```
> ${string:position:length}
> ```
>
> Extracts *`$length`* characters of substring from *`$string`* at *`$position`*.

**<kbd>NOTE</kbd> missing quotes around parameter expansions!** `echo` should not be used for arbitrary data.

```
stringZ=abcABC123ABCabc
#       0123456789.....
#       0-based indexing.

echo ${stringZ:0}                       # abcABC123ABCabc
echo ${stringZ:1}                       # bcABC123ABCabc
echo ${stringZ:7}                       # 23ABCabc 

echo ${stringZ:7:3}                     # 23A
                                        # Three characters of substring.


# Is it possible to index from the right end of the string?

echo ${stringZ:-4}                      # abcABC123ABCabc
# Defaults to full string, as in ${parameter:-default}.
# However . . . 

echo ${stringZ:(-4)}                    # Cabc
echo ${stringZ: -4}                     # Cabc
# Now, it works.
# Parentheses or added space "escape" the position parameter.
```

> The *position* and *length* arguments can be "parameterized," that is,
>   represented as a variable, rather than as a numerical constant.

---

> If the `$string` parameter is "*" or "@", then this extracts a maximum
>   of `$length` positional parameters, starting at `$position`.

```
echo ${*:2}          # Echoes second and following positional parameters.
echo ${@:2}          # Same as above.

echo ${*:2:3}        # Echoes three positional parameters, starting at second.
```

---

**<kbd>NOTE</kbd>: `expr substr` is a GNU extension.**

```
expr substr $string $position $length
```

> Extracts *`$length`* characters from *`$string`* starting at *`$position`*.

```
stringZ=abcABC123ABCabc
#       123456789......
#       1-based indexing.

echo `expr substr $stringZ 1 2`           # ab
echo `expr substr $stringZ 4 3`           # ABC
```

**<kbd>NOTE</kbd>: That `echo` is redundant and makes it even less reliable.** Use `expr substr + "$string1" 1 2`.

**<kbd>NOTE</kbd>**: `expr` will return with a non-zero exit status if the output is 0 (or -0, 00...).

---

BTW. The book is present in the official Ubuntu repository as `abs-guide`.

Comment: To say "position" is slightly misleading as it's actually an offset, which means that `${var:1}` doesn't return the value of `var` from the "1st position", but actually from the 2nd.

Comment: That's true, but as long as you don't agree there can be a zero-th position. Which is fine with me.

Answer (score 13):

In POSIX `sh`,

- `"${var%?????}"` is `$var` stripped of the last 5 trailing characters (or `$var` if `$var` contains fewer than 5 characters)
- `"${var%"${var#??????????}"}"` is the first 10 characters of `$var`.
- `"${var%_*}"` is `$var` stripped of the shortest string that matches `_*` at the end of `$var` (`foo_bar_baz` -> `foo_bar`).
- `"${var%%_*}"`: same but longest match instead of shortest match (`foo_bar_baz` -> `foo`).
- if you wanted to get `foo_bar_`: `"${var%"${var##*_}"}"` (`${var##pattern}` is the same as `${var%%pattern}` but looking for the pattern at the beginning of `$var` instead of the end).

With `zsh`:

- `$var[1,-6]` for first character to 6th from the end (so all but the last 5).
- `$var[1,10]` for first 10 characters.

With `ksh`, `bash` or `zsh`:

- `"${var:0:10}"`: first 10 characters of `$var`

With `bash` or `zsh`:

- `"${var:0:-5}"`: all but the last 5 characters (gives an error and exits the script if `$var` is set but contains fewer than 5 characters, also when `$var` is not set with `zsh`).

If you need Bourne `sh` compatibility, it's very difficult to do reliably. If you can guarantee the result won't end in newline characters you can do:

```
first_10=`expr " $var" : ' \(.{1,10\}\)'` # beware the exit status
                                          # may be non-zero if the
                                          # result is 0 or 0000000000

all_but_last_5=`expr " $var" : ' \(.*\).\{5\}'`
```

You'll also have a limit on the length of `$var` (varying between systems).

In all those solutions, if `$var` contains bytes that can't form part of valid characters, YMMV.

Comment: my, they really came up with some ugly syntax for inside those braces.

Answer (score 2):

`sh` doesn't provide a built-in way of getting a substring out of a string (as far as I can see), but with `bash` you may do

```
${i:0:10}
```

This will give you the first ten characters of the value of the variable `i`.

The general format is `${variable:offset:length}`.

Answer (score 2):

Most shells support some kind of parameter expansion that can help you. In bash, you can use

```
substr=${string:4:5} # start at position 4, length 5.
```

In `dash`, offsets are not supported, but you can use leading and trailing patterns:

```
remove_first3=${string#???}
remove_last2=${string%??}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't use a `for` loop for file names.

Then, something like this should help.

```
find ./ -type f | while read filename ;do
  newfilename=$(echo ${filename}|cut -c 1-10)
  mv ${filename} ${newfilename}
done
```

Comment: Why is it bad to use `for` with file names?

Comment: Quote your variables and use `printf` to be safer.  ... and `read -r`.

Comment: The OP's `for` loop was fine except  maybe for the missing `--`. I can see at least 10 bugs in your 4 lines of code! many of which well known bad practice like assuming file names are single line, use echo, missing quotes