# String editting in a for loop

Tags: bash

The code below crops blank pdf image borders. The output file of the example below contains the tail "_cropped" before the extension ".pdf". Indexing a string might be a good solution to take the tail out. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303960/index-a-string-in-bash) URL provides an explanation for indexing. I do not know how to assign the respective filename to a variable and change its name by `<old-name> <new-name>`. Any help is appreciated. :)

```
for f in *; do
    pdf-crop-margins -v -p 0 -a -6 "$(basename $f .pdf).pdf";
done
```

Comment: To me it is a bit unclear what you want. Does the program make an `example.pdf` to an `example_cropped.pdf`? And what do you want to do next? Please try to be a bit more clear what you are given, what you desire as output and maybe add an example.

Comment: I edited the file for better comprehension.

Comment: So you want to manipulate the filename string?

Comment: yes, I want to edit it.

Comment: How do you want to edit it? From what to what?

Comment: I want to remove the "_cropped" snippet from the file name.

Comment: Oh is that all? `f="somefile_cropped.pdf"; echo "${f/_cropped/}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input for `$f` : `example_cropped.pdf`, output: `example.pdf`.

- Option 1, your `basename` approach:

  ```
  echo $(basename "$f" _cropped.pdf).pdf
  ```
- Option 2, `sed`

  ```
  sed 's/_cropped//' <<< "$f"
  ```
- Option 3, `rename` - to be applied to files rather than strings. Will directly rename the file, use `-n` for dry run:

  ```
  rename 's/_cropped//' "$f"
  ```

`rename` may also be applied to multiple files in one go, maybe that is what you actually need.

Answer (score 1):

In bash substitution is quite effective:

```
v="file_cropped.pdf"
# file_cropped.pdf

echo ${v%_cropp*}.pdf
# file.pdf
```